# Vue Web App Blank on Some iPhones, but fine on all other devices

Tags: ios, vue.js

I created a webapp in Vue several months back and have been using it for some time. I've used it on Android, iPhone, Mac, Windows, and all was good in the beginning, however a couple of months back, I began noticing that the page would sometimes load on iPhone, and sometimes not. It worked perfectly fine on every Android I've tried without issue, works on Mac and on Windows, though iPhone seems to be hit or miss (haven't tried it on any other iOS/iPadOS devices), and I have no idea where to start. I know this doesn't give a lot of information to begin with, but I'm not sure how to even begin debugging this. What I have tried so far:

- Resetting cache - did not fix
- Using various browsers - blank page across Safari, Chrome, in private/incognito modes and normal modes
- Tried different iPhones - would work without issue on some, but not on others

I have not touched the Vue config file, is there some support issue between specific iOS versions and Vue that I'm not aware of?

Again, I know there's not much detail provided other than "It doesn't work", but I honestly don't know what else to try or what information I might be able to use - if there is something additional I need to provide, let me know and I can update the post with the information.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it on a device you can plug into a Mac and use Safari web inspector to view the console logs? https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-debug-on-iphone

Comment: It's been hard for me to get access to both a mac and iPhone that can reproduce the issue simultaneously, but I will give this a shot if whenever I get the chance. I was unaware that this was a thing. In the meantime, assuming I can't, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: This is almost certainly depends on your app, not Vue itself. *Tried different iPhones - would work without issue on some, but not on others* - it's iOS version that matters, you you could start with comparing them. Safari on iOS and Mac share the same engine (Webkit), I'm quite sure you couldn't check a variety of desktop Safari versions, so the one you tried didn't have issues. You could start with remote (Browserstack, etc) or some Webkit browser.

Comment: I'm going to see if I can figure out any patterns between the devices with iOS version, etc., as suggested. I took a look at Browserstack, and all of the Apple devices (iPhone, iPad, Mac) all resulted in a blank page, though I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: @Sal It helps you because they can be debugged at Browserstack.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. My vue app works fine on all devices: Mac, Windows, Ubuntu. But, it's blank both on chrome & safari on iPhone.

Comment: @user1896653 I realized the issue was that I was trying to use a built-in library that wasn't supported on iOS, but was on the other browsers/OS, I believe it was the speech library. Try Browserstack to debug the issue